# avoid calling sigchld handler in a part of the code

Tags: c, signals, posix

I got a SIGCHLD handler on my program that reaps zombie processes.

How can I avoid calling the SIGCHLD handler in a part of the code where I'm doing multiple fork() calls and waitpid() calls?

Because right now, when I make a fork() call and the child finishes his execution, it returns a SIGCHLD signal so it calls the SIGCHLD handler, but I want to reap the process in that part of the code instead of in the handler?

How can I do that? Blocking SIGCHLD signal?

Comment: Have you tried blocking it and seeing if that works the way you want?

Comment: If you want the default behaviour, reinstate SIG_DFL handling while you don’t want SIGCHLD handled by your signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGCHLD);
   s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
```

At a later time, when you done with this, use SIG_UNBLOCK to unblock the sig handler.